# Overlap images in an L-shaped container?

Tags: css, image, overlap

I've been searching around a little bit here and this is what I was able to do. I'm green on anything that has to do with webdesign so don't be too harsh please. :P

http://jsfiddle.net/rPAPz/141/

html

```
<div class="container-3">
  <div class="top"><img class="img1" src="http://dummyimage.com/200/ccc/000.png&text=image+1" />
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"><img  src="http://dummyimage.com/200/ccc/000.png&text=image+5" width="202" height="210" class="img5" /></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.img1{top:0px; left:0px; z-index:1;opacity:.5}

.img2{top:10px; right:110px; z-index:2;opacity:.5}

.container-3{    
  position:absolute; 
}

.top{   
  width: 200px;  
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  border:blue solid 2px;
  border-bottom:none;
  position:relative;
  z-index:4;
} 

.bottom{
  z-index:2;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:0;
  border: blue solid 2px;
  background:red;
}
```

Got the images right now (I think) but I dont know how to position it right. I would like the end result to look [like this](http://i1081.photobucket.com/albums/j359/hetsig/testest_zps6876a446.png)

html:

```
<p>Etvab luxury estates är en webportal för den kräsne bostadsköparen.

Här har vi samlat ett representativt urval av de mest

exklusiva bostäderna på Spaniens södra kust.

Bostäder med unika lägen – havsnära eller örnnästen.

Bostäder med förfinad design.

Bostäder med vyer som är ”breathtaking”.

Bostäder med luft och ytor som andas välbefinnande.

Bostäder som har allti modern utrustning och senaste teknologi.

Vi har medvetet lagt ribban högt, för att kittla fantasin, ge en svindlande

resa i tid och rum och visa det bästa av spansk modern arkitektur.

Vi har i första hand valt bostäder med lägen och kvalitet

som är i absolut topskikt.

Vi har inte tittat på status i områden

då vi bedömer att det inte avgör bostadens värde och attraktion.

Vår ambition är att förnya dessa sidor regelbundet, till nöje

och nytta för den som söker inspiration till ett husköp

med högsta kvalitet och läge.

Men även för den som njuter av design och vackra miljöer

- på avstånd.</div>     
<p>&nbsp;<br>
</p>


 <style>
    .qs_input { height:40px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 8px; background: #f3f3f3; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; border-bottom: 2px solid #d7d6d6; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; font-size: 1.0 em;}
    .the_table {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; font-size: 0.8em;}
    .fastighet { padding:5px;}
    .inne { padding:8px 0px 8px 8px;  height:15px;}
</style>
 <div id='qsResale' class='qs_body' style='width:50%; float:right; margin-left: 15px; padding:0px; margin: 0px;'>
<form name='qsFormResale' id='qsFormResale' method='post' action='search.php'>
<table class="the_table" style='width:98%; float:left;'>
    <tr><td class='qs_label' style='width:98%;'><h7>Typ av fastighet</h7></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
<select class='qs_input fastighet' name='Type' id='Type' style='width:90%;'>
<option class='qs_input' value='No Preference'></option>
<option class='qs_input' value='S'>Studio</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='A'>Lägenhet</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='T'>Radhus</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='V'>Villa</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='P'>Tomt</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='C'>Kommersiella</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='AS'>Lägenhet & Studio</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='AT'>Lägenhet & radhus</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='AV'>Lägenhet & villa</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='TV'>Radhus & villa</option>
</select>
        </td>
    </tr>


        <tr><td class='qs_label' style='vertical-align:top;'><h7>Kust</h7></td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <select class='qs_input fastighet' name="Area" id="Area" onchange="cambia(this, document.qsFormResale.Location);" style='width:90%;'> 
            <option value='Costa de la Luz'>Costa de la Luz</option>
            <option value='Costa del Sol'>Costa del Sol</option>
            <option value='Costa del Sol East'>Costa del Sol East</option>
            <option value='Granada (Costa Tropical)'>Granada (Costa Tropical)</option>
            <option value='Almería (Costa Almería)'>Almería (Costa Almería)</option>
            <option value='Murcia (Costa Calida)'>Murcia (Costa Calida)</option>
            <option value='Alicante (Costa Blanca)'>Alicante (Costa Blanca)</option>
            <option value='Costa Azahar'>Costa Azahar</option>
            <option value='Costa Brava'>Costa Brava</option>
            <option value='Costa Dorada'>Costa Dorada</option>
            <option value='Ibiza'>Ibiza</option>
            <option value='Cordoba'>Cordoba</option>
            <option value='Tenerife'>Tenerife</option>
            <option value='Mallorca'>Mallorca</option>

            </select>

            </td>
        </tr>



    <tr>
      <td class='qs_label' style='vertical-align:top;'><h7>Område</h7></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <select class='qs_input' size='5' style="height:150px; width:395px;" name='Location' id='Location' multiple='multiple' style='width:90%;'>
        <option class='qs_input inne' value='No Preference'>Ingen Preferens</option>
        <option class='qs_input inne' value='Ayamonte'>Ayamonte</option>
        <option class='qs_input inne' value='Huelva'>Huelva</option>
        <option class='qs_input inne' value='Sanlucar de Barrameda'>Sanlucar de Barrameda</option>
        <option class='qs_input inne' value='Tarifa'>Tarifa</option>
        <option class='qs_input inne' value='Jimena de la Frontera'>Jimena de la Frontera</option>
        <option class='qs_input inne' value='San Pablo de Buceite'>San Pablo de Buceite</option>
        <option class='qs_input inne' value='Jerez de la Frontera'>Jerez de la Frontera</option>
        <option class='qs_input inne' value='Cadiz'>Cádiz</option>
        <option class='qs_input inne' value='Olvera'>Olvera</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td class='qs_label'><h7>Sovrum</h7></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <select size='1' class='qs_input fastighet' name='Beds' id='Beds' style='width:90%;'>
<option class='qs_input' value='No Preference'>Ingen Preferens</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='1'>1 Bädd</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='1x'>1 Bädd eller fler</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='2'>2 Bäddar</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='2x'>2 Bäddar eller fler</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='3'>3 Bäddar</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='3x'>3 Bäddar eller fler</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='4'>4 Bäddar</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='4x'>4 Bäddar eller fler</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='5'>5 Bäddar</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='5x'>5 Bäddar eller fler</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='6'>6 Bäddar</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='6x'>6 Bäddar eller fler</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='7'>7 Bäddar</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='7x'>7 Bäddar eller fler</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='8'>8 Bäddar</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='8x'>8 Bäddar eller fler</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='9'>9 Bäddar</option>
<option class='qs_input' value='9x'>9 Bäddar eller fler</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td class='qs_label'><h7>Pris från</h7></td></tr>
    <tr><td><p>
      <input type='text' class='qs_input' id='PriceMin' name='PriceMin' style='width:80%;' value='0' maxlength='8' onChange='return f_checkNumber(this,0,0);'>
          &nbsp;<span class='qs_text'>&euro;</span></p></td></tr>

    <tr>
      <td class='qs_label'><h7>Pris upp till</h7></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type='text' class='qs_input' id='PriceMax' name='PriceMax' style='width:80%;' value='0' maxlength='8' onChange='return f_checkNumber(this,0,0);'>&nbsp;<span class='qs_text'>&euro;</span></td></tr>

    <tr>
      <td class='qs_label'><h7>Referens nr</h7></td></tr>
    <tr><td style='padding-right:5%;'><input type='text' class='qs_input' id='RefNum' name='RefNum' value='' maxlength='12'></td></tr>

    <tr><td style='padding-top:10px;'><input type='submit' input type='button' class="button-5" value="Sök"></td></tr>
</table>

<input type='hidden' name='P1' id='P1' value='ETvabResales'>
<input type='hidden' name='P2' id='P2' value='R'>
<input type='hidden' name='P3' id='P3' value='ALL'>
<input type='hidden' name='QS' id='QS' value='RESALE'>
<input type='hidden' name='Country' id='Country' value='Spain'>
<input type='hidden' name='RentalType' id='RentalType' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='RentalDateFrom' id='RentalDateFrom' value='06-02-2013'>
<input type='hidden' name='RentalDateTo' id='RentalDateTo' value='06-02-2013'>
<input type='hidden' name='Language' id='Language' value='8'>
<input type='hidden' name='CustomArea' id='CustomArea' value=''>
</form>         
            </div>


        </div>

     <div class="clear"></div>  


 </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you want to have top div stacked above bottom div, but in the same time you want images inside these two divs to have their own stack order depending of each other?

In this

```
<div class="container-3">
  <div class="top"><img class="img1" src="http://dummyimage.com/200/ccc/000.png&text=image+1" />
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"><img  src="http://dummyimage.com/200/ccc/000.png&text=image+5" width="202" height="210" class="img2" /></div>
</div>
```

When you set z-index to divs (parent elements) you cannot set (you can, but it won't work) the z-index to images in those divs and expect that they will be stacked depending of each other.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BRANIS/rPAPz/142/)

Comment: I see that I was wrong in one thing. I overlooked that absolute positioned elements does make them independent with z-index because `position: absolute;` excludes element from document flow relative to parent element if there's any or html element itself, while `position: relative;` exclude element from document flow, but keeps them relative to it self. Little bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things: for the images, to use `top` and `left`, they need to have `position:absolute`. `position:relative` should be given to the containing div, so I've moved it to:

```
.container-3{    
  position:relative; 
}
```

and then given `position:absolute` to .top

This allows both images and both text areas to be stacked independently. Some of the positioning needed to then be adjusted, since it was all relative to `.container-3`, and some of the z-index values needed to be adjusted.

You can see the results at:
http://jsfiddle.net/rPAPz/143/

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: yup exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I got the images rdy now but I dont rly know how to position it right...

Comment: Glad it works. In terms of position, just play with the top and left values, but remember they are all relative to the top and left of container-3.